# Firefox is not sending allocate request to TURN server to get relay candidates

Tags: firefox, webrtc, turn, ice

Find below logs from about webrtc while checking with trickle ICE.
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

ICE(PC:{f8be271e-a104-46d0-9666-1f5c4804b8e3} 1673540416421000 (id=6442450948 url=https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peercon): failed to resolve candidate relay(IP4:192.168.14.18:58951/UDP|IP4:0.0.0.0:3478/UDP).

Tried with other browsers on the same machine but did not face any issues. Cannot generate relay candidates in firefox browser alone. Even tried after reinstalling the browser.
In wireshark packet trace, I can see that there is not STUN request from the browser to the TURN server.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is your TURN ip, in almost TURN server config, it recommend to use public ip, for local development then can just be your local ip, avoid using 127.0.0.1 as some browsers discard from that ip

Answer (score 1):

On windows, u can ipconfig then replace the IPv4 Address instead of 0.0.0.0